# How to create multi language menu in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-routing

What is the best way to create a main menu in Laravel 5? And how to show menu items only when an user is logged-in? And What is the best way to make this multi language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel provides an easy way to check if the user is logged-in by using the facade `Auth::check()`.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

About the translation, you can check here: [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization)

The structure is defined like this, as per documentation:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /es
            messages.php
```

Laravel also provides an easy way to translate phrases using the `trans('string.to.translate')`, which can be seen here [trans()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-trans).

Inside messages.php (in both lang directories), you must set the translation string. In `en/messages.php`:

```
    return [
        'welcome' => 'Welcome'
    ];
```

In `es/messages.php`:

```
    return [
        'welcome' => 'Bienvenido'
    ];
```

With these two, you can do the following in you application for example:

```
    // Get the user locale, for the sake of clarity, I'll use a fixed string.
    // Make sure is the same as the directory under lang.
    App::setLocale('en');
```

Inside your `view`:

```
    // Using blade, we check if the user is logged in.
    // If he is, we show 'Welcome" in the menu. If the lang is set to
    // 'es', then it will show "Bienvenido".
    @if (Auth::check()) 
        <ul>
            <li> {{ trans('messages.welcome') }} </li>
        </ul>
    @endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

For example:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return something to view
}
```